# Not getting correct date in Carbon parse

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, php-carbon, voyager

I'm using laravel 5.6 and adding a date through dx data grid, however it is giving a current date which is not what I selected.

I have tried to change the date format, but in this case, the date is correct. After first insertion it is giving me wrong date (i.e. 1970-01-01).

```
$grids = $request->except('_token');
$request->request->set('attendance_date', Carbon::parse($request- 
>attendance_date)->format('Y-m-d'));

$grids=array();
$grids['name'] = $request['item']['name'];
$grids['attendance_type'] = $request['item']['attendance_type'];
$grids['dept'] = $request['item']['dept'];
$grids['user_id'] = $request['item']['user_id'];
$grids['attendance_date'] = $request->attendance_date;
$grids['attendance_month'] = $request->attendance_month;
$grids['attendance_year'] = $request->attendance_year;
$grids['org_name'] = $request->org_name;
$grids['org_id'] = $request->org_id;
dd($grids);

  $requesteddate = $request->attendance_date;
  $requesteduser_id = $grids['user_id'];
  $attendances = DB::table('attendances')->where(['user_id' => 
  $requesteduser_id])->get()->toArray();
   foreach ($attendances as $key => $value) {
    $dbattendance_date = $value->attendance_date;
    $dbattendance_user_id = $value->user_id;

    if ($dbattendance_date == $requesteddate && $dbattendance_user_id == 
       $requesteduser_id) {

        $insert['status'] = 'error';
        $insert['message'] = 'Attendance Already Exits';
        return Response()->json($insert);

    }
}
$insert = Attendance::create($grids);
return Response()->json($insert);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by this.

```
$newattendance_date = $request['item']['attendance_date'];
    if(strpos($newattendance_date,' GMT') !== false){
        $newattendance_date = substr($newattendance_date,0,strpos($newattendance_date,' GMT'));
        $newattendance_date = strtotime($newattendance_date);
        $newattendance_date =  date('Y-m-d', $newattendance_date); 
    }
    $attendance_date= $newattendance_date;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some irrelevant information here in your question, and a few questions I would need to know to be more accurate. That being said, here are a few possibilities I suspect might be occurring:

### Possibility #1

**You have error reporting turned off.** There is a wide variety of reasons why you may not get the correct date, and often times [with error reporting turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) you will see the reason. For example, your usage of `$request->attendance_date` may be returning a `null` value, resulting in the parse falling back to the first UTC date possible.

### Possibility #2

You are doing `$request->request->set('attendance_date'`... instead of `$request->set('attendance_date'`. Not sure why you are doing this, but later on when you try to use `$request->attendance_date` is will by a `null` value because it never got set correctly. Again, you would see this problem probably with error reporting/display errrors turned on.

### Possibility #3

The date passed in your `Request` input is wrong. This could be anything from an empty string to an invalid date. A good rule of thumb is if PHP's native `strtotime()` function can parse it correctly, then Carbon can too.